# What prompts Windows (8.1) to mark WiFi connections with this warning?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8

Why does Windows mark certain WiFi connections with an exclamation mark and not others?

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are "open" networks, e.g, not transmitted with strong encryption and thus subject to sniffing.

If you send all traffic over a secure VPN or SSH tunnel, this ok. Also, certain man in the middle vulnerability risks excepted, TLS protected packets are safe.

Other than those scenarios your traffic can be sniffed over an open wireless connection

Comment: Which means that someone encouraging you to use their free wifi might be looking to steal your info

Comment: I'm imagining the skeezy, dirty van trolling through the neighborhood offering the kids "free candy."

Comment: @schroeder, someone encouraging you to use their free wifi will be able to steal your info whether it is password-protected or not.

Comment: Not really. A lot of captive portal especially those at cafe are open networks. That does not make them safe, just that its easier to implement such a solution when you do not know the users and cant really authenticate them.